# Performance way of working on SQL Server data tables at C# code behind

Tags: c#-4.0, sql-server-2008-r2, dataset, dataview

Alright now the question may come to you vague so I will try to explain as much as possible.

For example I have 10 columns and 5000 rows in a data table called `tblNpc`.

So I will make a lot of filtering on this table during the work. I am using this approach here, but is that the best way of handling it?

Here a small example

```
    string srQuery = "select * from tblNpc";
    DataSet dsNPC = DbConnection.db_Select_Query(srQuery);

    DataView dvNPC = new DataView(dsNPC.Tables[0]);

    dvNPC.RowFilter = "npcId=32";
    string srExampleData = dvNPC[0]["npcName"].ToString();
```

C# 4.0, SQL Server 2008 R2

Important: I will use entire table and will do filtering equal to entire table row count

Comment: It'll be a bit faster if you use `select * from tblNpc where npcId = 32`.  Then only one row has to be transferred from the database to the client program.

Comment: well think about that i will use entire table and will do filtering equal to entire table row count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per `@Andormar's` comments, it would be quicker if you `hand over the filtering job to the SQL Server`, which is designed to do the job, in the first place and `bring over only what you needed.`

If you need to work with the DataTable in the code behind, then `LINQ would be quicker I think`. On top of that you could do complex queries with your DataTable with LINQ rather than RowFilter.

For example your query can be done as

```
var results = (from r in dsNPC.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
               where r.Field<int>("npcId")) ==32
               select new { npcName = r.Field<string>("npcName")})
              .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: +1. Prefixixint Tables with "tbl" (why? You dont know databases work with tables? Leanr your trade) is as bad, but in generally - I always wnoder how people think a DataSet (known to be large, slow, bad) is better than a sql server for that.

Comment: thanks a lot kind of answer i am looking for. @TomTom querying server is a lot a lot more slow than querying the object in the ram. as i said imagine that i am doing filtering equal to row count in entire table.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG That smells like too little ram on server or bad indices etc.